# For-in Loop through Tumblr posts with ajax

Tags: ajax, tumblr

The expectation is that `$(".post-title").append(postTitle);` will return the title of that post, as will postBody. Yet when I console.log these variables `> undefined` is returned.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/ohc-gallery.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=***",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(res){
      var postings = res.response.posts;
      var postTitle = "";
      var postBody = "";
        $(".post-title").append(postTitle);
        $(".post-body").append(postBody);

        for (var i in postings){
            postTitle = postings[i].title;
            postBody = postings[i].body;
        }
            console.log("postBody: " + postBody);

    }
});
```

Am I missing something basic regarding Javascript closures... I really don't know right now. I simply want to loop through created post data for later display.

Github JS code- https://github.com/mrcn/ohc/blob/master/js/tumblr.js

Github HTML code- https://github.com/mrcn/ohc/blob/master/index-posting.html#L82-L89

I got it. The problem was with how I intended to display this information on the website, and I had to alter the code accordingly. The idea was to display paired blog post titles and entries. The problem was all titles were appearing together, and all bodies were appearing together- not paired off respectively.

The updated code is more along the lines of --

Javascript --

```
        //use $.each() or Array.forEach
        $.each(postings, function (i, post) {
            $(".post ").append("<h3>" + post.title + "</h3>" + post.body + "<br><br>");

        });
    }
});
```

HTML --

```
             <div class="post-wrap"><!--post-wrap-->
                    <div class="post">

                    </div>
                </div><!--post-wrap-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) is used to iterate over an object... posts is an array for you can use the normal `for (var i=0;i<x;i++)` loop or any other iteration methods like [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) or [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/ohc-gallery.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=***',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (res) {
        var postings = res.response.posts;
        var postTitle = '';
        var postBody = '';

        //use $.each() or Array.forEach
        $.each(postings, function (i, post) {
            $(".post-title ").append(post.title);
            $(".post-body ").append(post.body);
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: the tip is helpful, this code is not working however. i am still searching for a solution.

Comment: @mrcni what is it that you want to do

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I can't believe I didn't even mention this in my original post- I think I was trying to narrow the problem down and expected something different from the code. 

I am trying to get code to output a single post title followed by a single post body, and to repeat this for all posts. This code is currently putting all post titles together, and all post bodies together.

Comment: can you share the target html and to which element you want to add the contents

Comment: I updated the HTML link to the correct page with the code highlighted.

Comment: For as much information as I gave you, you answered the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not every post type supports `title` or `body`. You currently have three posts, two text and one photo. The photo post type only support `photos` and `caption`, which is causing the `undefined`.

Check the API for more details: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2